# book on human sexuality evolution

Tags: evolution, book-recommendation, sexuality

i am interested in Lynn Margulis' book Mystery Dance: On the Evolution of Human Sexuality.

i don't find it in libraries and it's too old and i am too poor for paying 20 euros for a 1991 book.

Does anybody know a more modern book about human sexuality evolution?

Comment: Perhaps *The Evolution of Desire* by David M. Buss. I haven't read it myself (yet), but I've had it recommended.

Answer (score 1):

**Wild connection** by Jennifer Verdolin is good, it shows the source of many of humanities sexual behaviors, but it really depends on what you are looking for is there a specific area you are trying to learn about?

The Third chimpanzee might interest you, it compares human behavior to the other chimpanzee species, sex is only a small part but it is there.

I a can warn you against a book I used to like,*sperm wars* by Baker, A lot of the research is his own and there have been a lot of issues with people being unable to replicate many of them, so a lot of it untrustworthy, which is a shame because I really liked his writing style.